# How can I determine the location of the XML namespace on Java (JAXB or another method)?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

I'm using JAXB to marshall an Java object to XML.

Example;

**com.abc.Defter.java** object **package-info.java**:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com",
    xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.example.com", prefix = "abc")})
package com.abc;
```

**com.xyz.Xbrl.java** object **package-info.java**:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example2.com",
    xmlns = {@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(namespaceURI = "http://www.example2.com", prefix = "xyz")})
package com.xyz;
```

Marshalling result xml string;

```
<abc:defter xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com" xmlns:xyz="http://www.example2.com">
   <xyz:xbrl>
      <xyz:unit id="try">
         <measure>iso4217:TRY</measure>
      </xyz:unit>
   </xyz:xbrl>
</abc:defter>
```

***All namespaces are in the root directory, but I do not want it***. I would like the following example;

```
<abc:defter xmlns:abc="http://www.example.com">
    <xyz:xbrl xmlns:xyz="http://www.example2.com">
        <xyz:unit id="try">
            <measure>iso4217:TRY</measure>
        </xyz:unit>
    </xyz:xbrl>
</abc:defter>
```

How can I do it JAXB or another method using?

Comment: Why does it matter where namespaces are declared?

Comment: I can not give a meaning but this is a business request :(